# SFML Tilemap doesn't render from a .txt file as it should

Tags: c++, drawing, rendering, render, sfml

I'm trying to make a Pacman game. So far I have only ghost which I can move with arrow keys and I wanted to make a tilemap, but my program draws it differently than in .txt file and I don't know why. [Here's an image of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEDi1.png)

Those are my files:

main.cpp

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

#include "tilemap.hpp"

int main()
{
    // WINDOW
    sf::RenderWindow appWindow( sf::VideoMode( 1280, 1024, 32 ), "Pacman" );
    appWindow.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);

    // IMAGES
    sf::Texture spriteSheet;
    spriteSheet.loadFromFile( "spriteSheet.png" );
    sf::Image test;
    test.create(1280, 1024, sf::Color::Black);

    // SPRITES
    sf::Sprite ghostSprite;
    ghostSprite.setTexture( spriteSheet );
    ghostSprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect( 0, 0, 64, 64 ));
    ghostSprite.setOrigin( 32, 32 );
    ghostSprite.setPosition( 400, 300 );

    bool upPressed = false;
    bool leftPressed = false;
    bool rightPressed = false;
    bool downPressed = false;

    while( appWindow.isOpen() )
    {

        sf::Event event;
        while( appWindow.pollEvent( event ) )
        {
            if(( event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape) || event.type == sf::Event::Closed )
            {
                appWindow.close();
            }
            if( event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Up )
            {
                upPressed = true;
                leftPressed = false;
                rightPressed = false;
                downPressed = false;
            }
            if( event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Left )
            {
                upPressed = false;
                leftPressed = true;
                rightPressed = false;
                downPressed = false;
            }
            if( event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Right )
            {
                upPressed = false;
                leftPressed = false;
                rightPressed = true;
                downPressed = false;
            }
            if( event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Down )
            {
                upPressed = false;
                leftPressed = false;
                rightPressed = false;
                downPressed = true;
            }

        }


        if( upPressed )
        {
            ghostSprite.move( 0, -6 );
            ghostSprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect( 132, 0, 64, 64 ));

        }
        if( downPressed )
        {
            ghostSprite.move( 0, 6 );
            ghostSprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect( 198, 0, 64, 64 ));
        }
        if( rightPressed )
        {
            ghostSprite.move( 6, 0 );
            ghostSprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect( 0, 0, 64, 64 ));
        }
        if( leftPressed )
        {
            ghostSprite.move( -6, 0 );
            ghostSprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect( 66, 0, 64, 64 ));
        }


        appWindow.clear( sf::Color::Black );
        appWindow.draw( ghostSprite );
        generateMap(appWindow);
        appWindow.display();

        sf::sleep(sf::microseconds(100));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

tilemap.cpp

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include "tilemap.hpp"

void generateMap(sf::RenderWindow &window)
{
    std::ifstream openfile("Map2.txt");

    sf::Texture tileTexture;
    sf::Sprite tiles;

    sf::Vector2i map[100][100];
    sf::Vector2i loadCounter = sf::Vector2i(0,0);

    if(openfile.is_open())
    {
        std::string tileLocation;
        tileLocation = "tile.png";
        tileTexture.loadFromFile(tileLocation);
        tiles.setTexture(tileTexture);

        while(!openfile.eof())
        {
            std::string str;
            openfile >> str;
            char x = str[0];
            char y = str[2];
            if(!isdigit(x) || !isdigit(y))
            {
                map[loadCounter.x][loadCounter.y] = sf::Vector2i(-1,-1);
            }
            else
            {
                map[loadCounter.x][loadCounter.y] = sf::Vector2i(x - '0', y - '0');
            }

            if(openfile.peek() == '\n')
            {
                loadCounter.x = 0;
                loadCounter.y++;
            }
            else
            {
                loadCounter.x++;
            }


            for(int i = 0; i < loadCounter.x; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < loadCounter.y; j++)
                {
                    if(map[i][j].x != -1 && map[i][j].y != -1)
                    {
                        tiles.setPosition(i * 32, j * 32);

                    }
                }
            }
            window.draw(tiles);
        }
    }
}
```

and tilemap.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

void generateMap(sf::RenderWindow &window);
```

I'm new in making games so I wouldn't be suprised if I missed something.

Comment: You should change the texturerect of you pacman each time it changes direction, not each time it moves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start by giving you a tip to avoid that kind of thing:

```
            if( event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Up )
        {
            upPressed = true;
            leftPressed = false;
            rightPressed = false;
            downPressed = false;
        }
```

Just store your pressedKey variable within an enum that takes either LEFT, RIGHT, UP and DOWN, and change its value once for each key pressed
Now here's how to read your file:

```
std::string line;
int lineCount = 0;
while (getline(openfile, line)) {
lineCount++
    for(int column = 0; mapLength; column++)
        if (line[column] = '1')
            map[lineCount][column] = 1;
        else
            map[lineCount][column] = -1; 
}
```

And what your file should look like:

```
0011001100
0011001100
0000001100
0000001111
```

Also, you should put all sprites in a vector/array and render them one by one

Comment: I managed to get it working with your code after some adjustments.  Instead of loading my map into Vector2i or an array I made it draw my tiles while reading my .txt map. Thanks!

Comment: First time using stackoverflow :P

Comment: It might be a little late to say it, but if you're directly drawing the files from the files and not saving them anywhere, there is no way to check if your PacMan is in a wall or not... same applies if you want to redraw your level each frame